# Hibernate/Lucene Fields added in Custom FieldBridge unknown when search is performed

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

We need to index different fields from one data property. This has been solved by implementing a FieldBridge, and adding the Fields there.
As seen in this example from the hibernate search reference:

```
/**
 * Store the date in 3 different fields - year, month, day - to ease the creation of RangeQuery per
 * year, month or day (eg get all the elements of December for the last 5 years).
 * @author Emmanuel Bernard
 */
public class DateSplitBridge implements FieldBridge {
    private final static TimeZone GMT = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");

    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document,
                    LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        Date date = (Date) value;
        Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(GMT);
        cal.setTime(date);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set year
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(
            name + ".year",
            String.valueOf( year ),
            document );

        // set month and pad it if needed
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(
            name + ".month",
            month < 10 ? "0" : "" + String.valueOf( month ),
            document );

        // set day and pad it if needed
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(
            name + ".day",
            day < 10 ? "0" : "" + String.valueOf( day ),
            document );
    }
}
//property
@FieldBridge(impl = DateSplitBridge.class)
private Date date;
```

Additionally to the example from above we set ours up as a twoWayFieldBridge:

```
 public class DateSplitBridge implements TwoWayFieldBridge {
    [...]
    @Override
    public Object get(String name, Document document) {
        final IndexableField field = document.getField(name);
        if (field != null) {
            return field.stringValue();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        return object.toString();
    }
```

The Problem is, when searching for one of the Fields defined via the FieldBridge, the search does not seem to know it:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to
> find field date.day in [...]  at
> org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.objectToString(DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.java:1052)

If the Fields are mapped (per annotation or API), the error does not occur:

```
//property
@Fields({@Field(name="date.day", bridge = @FieldBridge(impl=DateSplitBridge.class)),
        @Field(name="date.month", bridge = @FieldBridge(impl=DateSplitBridge.class)),
        @Field(name="date.year", bridge = @FieldBridge(impl=DateSplitBridge.class))})
private Date date;
```

But then an error comes up when indexing, because the Field is then defined in the mapping and the FieldBridge which causes this:

> 2021-09-08 08:42:50,063 ERROR
> org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler:71
> - HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000183: Unable to index instance of type [...]
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DocValuesField "date.day" appears more than once in
> this document (only one value is allowed per field) at
> org.apache.lucene.index.SortedDocValuesWriter.addValue(SortedDocValuesWriter.java:62)
> ...

How should this be handled? How do we propagate the Fields from the FieldBridge to the search, to make them searchable in the first Place?

Comment: The problem was solved by sticking to the idea of  @yrodiere:

_..If you can, you should really consider upgrading to Hibernate Search 6, where bridge support is much more powerful and better documented._

In the end the deadline had to be moved and the newest hibernate Version was used. We recommend to not stick to an outdated version, try to go all the way on this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your query, not in the bridge. The field defined by the first bridge is not named `day`, it's named `<whatever your property name is>.day`. In your case, that would be `date.day`.

See this part of the code:

```java
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(
            name + ".day", // HERE
            day < 10 ? "0" : "" + String.valueOf( day ),
            document );
```

Just change your query to use `date.day` instead of `day`.

Shameless plug: if you can, you should really consider [upgrading to Hibernate Search 6](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/#migrate), where [bridge support is much more powerful](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/#bridge-2.0) and [better documented](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge).

Comment: - Original Post edited
Thank you for pointing out, and I'm Sorry, this error came from adapting the problem to the given example "date". In the Real code one of the fields where the error happens is actually simply called "name", and it is correct in all occurrences, in the mapping, in the Bridge, in the search, and also in the error thrown...

Maybe going through to Hibernate 6 would have been less painful than it appeared, but as for now, deadlines will deny this.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Search is unable to turn the value you passed to the Search DSL into the value to use in the Lucene Query, because the field `date.day` is not referenced anywhere in the Hibernate Search metadata, so it doesn't know its expected type.

Have your bridge implement [`MetadataProvidingFieldBridge`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-useof-custom-numericfieldbridge-metadataproviding), so that Hibernate Search knows about the field.

If that doesn't work, you can always use [`.ignoreFieldBridge().ignoreAnalyzer()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_query_options) when building your query using the Search DSL. For example:

```java
queryBuilder.keyword()
    .onField( "date.day" )
    .ignoreFieldBridge().ignoreAnalyzer()
    .matching( "10" )
    .createQuery()
```

A reminder for other users who didn't see the other answer: if you can, you should really consider [upgrading to Hibernate Search 6](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/#migrate), where [bridge support is much more powerful](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/#bridge-2.0) and [better documented](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge).

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. Sadly, changing to MetadataProvidingFieldBridge did not change the behaviour. 

Without a @Field anotation the fields are written into the index document, but not available for the search (_Unable to find field date.day in [...] at_), the MetadataProvidingFieldBridge did not change this.


public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
  builder.field( name, FieldType.STRING );
  builder.field( name + ".eng", FieldType.STRING );

Comment: Also tested .ignoreFieldBridge().ignoreAnalyzer(), which did also not lead to success.